# Effect of 10-year UK ban on US Visa Lottery winner

Tags: usa, immigration

I would like to find out how a UK 10 year ban can affect a friend's chances of getting a US visa when he wins the US Visa Lottery.

Comment: Please do not type in ALL CAPITAL letters. Thank you.

Comment: **If** he wins… What was the reason for the ban? When did it begin?

Comment: his agent presented false bank statement in his application and was banned for 10 years on UK student VISA and it began 2021 November

Comment: [The US and the UK share immigration info](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/ddg#56988), so the US will know about the UK ban. I'm not sure anyone here can guess the answer to your question. I think the most likely response by the US will be to deny any application for a US visa or other benefit.

Comment: Presumably it would depend on whether such a ban (or any other reason) makes him inadmissible https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim

Comment: @Traveller What a remarkable list that is! I don't see anything there that would result in denial to this applicant. However, given the questions about mere entry or visa refusal asked of all new visa applicants, it strains credulity to think that an applicant who admits deceiving or is found to have attempted to deceive the UK in a similar matter would skate right through to approval.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica this line has potential to be a blocker, depending on how its read legally: "Any alien who, by fraud or willfully misrepresenting a material fact, seeks to procure (or has sought to procure or has procured) a visa, other documentation, or admission into the United States or other benefit provided under this chapter is inadmissible." - does it just apply to visas or documents just related to the US or *any* visa or document anywhere?

Comment: @Moo I saw that too. Its application is not explained...but the impetus to  refuse a visa with that UK record will stimulate the US visa examiner to review all the applicant's statements. I can easily imagine the applicant hoist on his own petard: if the prior UK deceit is admitted, the application will be denied; if prior deceit is denied but shown by the UK info, the application will be denied.

Comment: I don't think fraud or misrepresentation inadmissibility applies here, unless the UK refusal was omitted on the U.S. application. I believe the normal route of denial is that prior misrepresentations elsewhere and in any domain makes the candidate less credible in overturning the assumption of immigration intent; but the diversity visa is an immigrant visa so this doesn't apply either. But one should expect any documents submitted will be examined in minute details and any omission or misrepresentation even if not intentional may not get the benefit of doubts that one may otherwise have got.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I doubt a fact-based answer can be given. For fiscal year 2021, the most recent figures available, Investopedia reported that more than 23.2 million people applied to the green card lottery. Roughly 125,000 names are drawn, with only 50,000 green cards available. In other words, his chances are slim anyway, only around 0.2% of applicants are successful.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it's pretty clear to me that "visa" means "US visa," but I am sure that some government officials at least would argue the contrary, and I don't know whether it's ever gone to court, nor am I sufficiently familiar with statutory construction to have much of an idea how a court is likely to rule.  Surely, however, failing to disclose the UK history is a bad idea.